# Incorrect docker manifest generated

Tags: docker, docker-registry, nexus3

I'm building my project as a docker image and pushing it to an on-premise Nexus repository. The trouble is that *sometimes* the image is pushed with the wrong manifest version. If everything goes right the manifest should be:
`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`

But sometimes it will be:
`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws`

I did search around about this issue and I haven't been able to find much except for [this issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-24485) on sonatype. However, I find the nature of the problem unpredictable. It seems to me that specifying the manifest version is done automatically. Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?